# Images stack when animated

Tags: css, image, google-chrome

Since I've animated my images (a caption appears when hovered), the images stack vertically instead of horizontally when viewed on Chrome. Here is the url - http://goodyearsinc.com/releases

I've tried adding "float: left" to the img wrap which worked on Firefox but not on Chrome. I am pulling my hair out trying to work it out.

Here is the jsfiddle with the css - http://jsfiddle.net/8eTB2/

```
.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4
{
float:left;
} 
.img-wrap{
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px; 
}
.img-overlay{
background-color:#000;
bottom:0;
color:#fff;
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
position:absolute;
width:100%;
z-index:1000;
}
.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p{
padding:0 10px;
}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay{
opacity:0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
transition:opacity 0.25s;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide us with your code that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow. I've edited my answer with the relevant css. Won't happen again :)

Comment: For future references, only post the code that is relevant to the problem. If you have a lot of code that is relevant then you could use this great tool, http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: It's no problem as long as you learn from this! :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from the

```
.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4 {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adjusting the width manually, on Chrome the width is 327px where firefox showed 465px.